# Can a function be harmonic on a closed set?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives, harmonic-functions

If $u(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}$, then $u$ is twice continuously differentiable on $D$ and $\triangle u=0$ for all $(x,y) \in D =\{\ (x,y): |x|=|y| \}\ \backslash \{(0,0) \}$.

Can I say that $u$ is harmonic on $D$? even $D$ is not open and I think it is disconnected (I'm not sure about connectivity).

Comment: Have you tried to evaluate the function on $D$? What do you get? Note also that it can be extended by continuity in this case at $(0,0)$.

Comment: @KBS , yes, I did. I got $D$ by evaluating the first and second partial derivatives, and this set $D$ is the only set where $u$ is twice continuously differentiable function and satisfies Laplacian equation.

Comment: This is not what I have asked. I have asked if you tried to evaluate $u$ on $D$. The expression for $u$ simplifies over that set.

Comment: @KBS, yes, it is constant over $D$. But, what does that mean?

Comment: That means that it does not make much sense to consider this function over that set. You will to provide more context to your question in order to convince people that it makes sense.

Comment: @KBS, so can I say that $u$ is not harmonic in any subsets $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: No it is not on any open set of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @KBS, Thank you for the clarifications.

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard anyone say this, because I've never heard of anything useful following from "areas of harmonicity" that don't contain neighborhoods of points. Do you have some usefulness in mind, or are you just wondering?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC, the question in my homework asked to state region $D$ where $u$ is harmonic. When I started applying the requirements of being harmonic, I ended with the set described in the question, but my understanding that $D$ must be open and connected. This is why I posted this question this way.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The definition is on open sets. In the current case, I would say that you should mention the set $D$ as a solution with the caveat that it is not open. You can also add that the function is not harmonic on any open set of $\mathbb{R}^2$. That should place you in a safe condition.

Comment: Okay, yeah, that's sort of an obscure corner. Check your textbook's definition, but yes, "open set" is often required (it is in the Wikipedia definition). The stuff above about it being constant on that set doesn't seem applicable to me, but a response of "The Laplacian vanishes on $D$, but as the set isn't open (heck, its interior is empty), the function isn't harmonic on *any* set." would sound great to me.